# Common startup parameter doesn't act as SpecialFolders

Tags: vbscript, startup

if I want to create any shortcut of the Application I can use the following code

```
    Dim FileName
    FileName = objFSO.GetFileName(objFile)
    Set shortcut = 
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Startup") & + "\" + FileName + ".lnk")
```

But if I change the

```
.SpecialFolders("Startup")
```

parameter to

```
.SpecialFolders("Common Startup")
```

it doesn't work  is it not strange ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AllUsersStartup`? Did you do any research?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe.aspx).

Comment: Hımm yes You're right , Thank you now